# Multi-line efetch digging

Tags: covid-19, bash, sars-cov-2, perl, efetch

I'm using efetch to dig out a middle "envelope" protein within a viral genome specifically within fasta format. The code below works but may not be robust for an entire database. Thus I want to replace the two "perl" lines with formal code within the Entrez package. I tried using `efilter -query` but couldn't get it to work. Genome positions are one approach but are not absolute from one virus to another. Rewriting this may be the best option.

```
ncbi2=NC_002021
efetch -db protein -format gpc -id "$ncbi2" |\
xtract -pattern INSDSeq -element INSDQualifier_value |\
perl -p -e 's/^(.+?)\s+taxon.*.*\s+\b([A-Z]{300}[A-Z]+).*/>$1\n$2/'|\
perl -p -e "s/[\t \;\/]+/_/g"
```

Output

```
>InfluenzaAvirus_A_PuertoRico_8_1934
MDVNPTLLFLKVPAQNAISTTFPYTGD.....
```

I will provide a more detailed explanation shortly.
Any ideas welcome.

Comment: In the meantime, you could streamline the perl a little to `| perl -pe 's/^(.+?)\s+taxon.*envelope protein.*\s+\b([A-Z]{300}[A-Z]+).*nonstructural protein 1.*/>$1\n$2/; s/[\t ;\/]+/_/g`. There's no need to process the file twice and you also don't need to escape the `;` inside a character class.

Comment: Hi @terdon, yes and thanks now you've mentioned it, it's obvious.

Comment: Not exactly what you were looking for but may be you can use something like this? `efetch -db protein -format gpc -id "$ncbi2" | xtract -pattern INSDSeq_feature-table -group INSDFeature -if INSDFeature_key -equals 'mat_peptide' -tab '\n' -element INSDFeature_location,INSDQualifier_value | grep 'envelope'`

Comment: Perfect it works a treat @vkkodali. Huge thanks. A small amount of regex will finish the fasta format. Maybe you would like to provide a formal answer so I can sign this question as complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly what you were looking for but may be you can use something like this?

```
ncbi2=NC_002021
efetch -db protein -format gpc -id "$ncbi2" \
    | xtract -pattern INSDSeq_feature-table \
        -group INSDFeature \
        -if INSDFeature_key -equals 'mat_peptide' \
        -tab '\n' \
        -element INSDFeature_location,INSDQualifier_value \
    | grep 'Segment 2'
```

For explorations of the INSDSet XMLs, `xtract` has `-insd` option that you can use. In this particular case, you can do something like this:

```
efetch -db nuccore -id "$ncbi2" -format gpc \
    | xtract -insd mat_peptide product peptide
```

For more information, checkout [EDirect documentation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK179288/#_chapter6_Sequence_Records_) and some  [example queries](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK179288/#_chapter6_Examples_)

Comment: Thank you its perfect. Stacked together in a small subroutine and parsed with a bit of regex its fantastic. "esearch -query" is used to obtain the accession numbers.